# Why in my App [React-router v4-beta5] routing doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a simple app using React, and run
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8088` to check if the routing works fine.
http://0.0.0.0:8088/ showed me a Landing.js component as expected, but when go to this address : http://0.0.0.0:8088/products - I expected to see a Products.js component rendered, but it showed me root rout.
Here's the code of Routing app:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route'
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom/BrowserRouter'
import Switch from 'react-router-dom/Switch'
import Landing from './Landing'
import Products from './Products'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

const App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className='app'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact pattern='/' component={Landing} />
            <Route pattern='/products' component={Products} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
})

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct prop for your matching pattern in the Route element is *path*, not *pattern*:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
<Route path='/products' component={Products} />
<Route component={NoMatch} />
```

See API docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#route